# Probability of opening a cupboard on several tries with n keys

Tags: probability

> Surtini has $n$ keys, one of those keys will open her locked diary. If she opens it with random keys, and even after $k$ failed attempt with the key(s), she still keeps the key, what is the probability of picking the right one after $k$ tries?

I have tried to solve this problem as follows, but I am not sure if I got the right outcome :
[my solution1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKR9L.png)

My result is $\frac{n-1}{n^2k}$ for $k>1$, and $\frac1n$ for $k=1$

Comment: Question - why does the denominator stay as $n$? If I have 2 keys, what happens if the first key I pick is wrong?

Comment: @ConMan The $1/n$ is only valid when it is the first try, if there are two tries or more (using two keys or more), then  it uses $(n-1)/(n^(2k))$. But, still, I am not sure if I get it right.

Comment: Let $n = 2$. There is a 1/2 chance Surtini picks the correct key first try. If she does that, what happens when she tries to pick another key?

Comment: @ConMan If the first try, the successful rate will be 1/n  (since the amount of key is unknown, I use n) then on another try (2nd trial), the probability that the second key is the right one is probability that the first one failing * probability that the second one success = n-1/n * 1/n = (n-1)/n^2. Is that correct, please?

Comment: You're getting close, and the given answer basically has it. I specifically asked for you to consider the case when $n = 2$, because sometimes it's easiest to test simple values of $n$ and then build to arbitrary values.

Answer (score 1):

The probability she picks it right on any given try is 1/n, and she doesn't (n-1)/n. So the probability after k tries would be:

$\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\frac{n-1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}(\frac{n-1}{n})^2 + \frac{1}{n}(\frac{n-1}{n})^3 +  ......+ \frac{1}{n}(\frac{n-1}{n})^k $

(The probability she gets it on each time try multiplied by the probability she hasn't already got it)
This is a Geometric sum so subbing it into the formula with k terms and simplifying it a bit gave me:

$ 1-(\frac{n-1}{n})^k $

Comment: Alternative : $1$ minus the probability that each attempt fails : $$1 - \left[\frac{n-1}{n}\right]^k.$$